# Is it appropriate to update database from a javabean class?

Tags: java, mysql, javabeans

A little bit of context: I am creating somewhat of a game. In that game the player can own a house. The house may contain furniture objects, and those furniture may have custom textures set. One piece of furniture may contain different amounts of textures. A piece of furniture has several slots(0 - x) for textures.

The house class:

```
public class House {
      private List<Furniture> furniture;

      public House() {
           furniture = new ArrayList<Furniture>();
      }

      public List<Furniture> getFurniture() {
            return furniture;
      }

      public void addFurniture(Furniture furniture) {
             furniture.add(furniture);
      }
}
```

The furniture class:

```
 public class Furniture {
       private Map<Integer, Texture> textures;

       public Furniture() {
             textures = new HashMap<Integer, Texture>();
       }

       public void setTexture(int index, Texture texture) {
             textures.put(index, texture);
       }
 }
```

In player house furniture management GUI there will be something like this:

```
List<Furniture> furniture = house.getFurniture();
// Let's assume that player selected one piece of furniture which he wants to edit
Furniture furniture = .... // This is the one he selected.
// Later on he chooeses a texture and I set it:
furniture.setTexture(some_index, new Texture(...));
```

**The question**

Would it make sense to update my database from inside the setTexture method? Is it good practice to interact with the datastore from within a data holding class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, it's not a good practice to make update directly in these java beans. You should use a DAO pattern. 
In this way, you can abstract all the CRUD operation on the model.

For more detailed information, you should visit [DAO pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/data_access_object_pattern.htm)

Comment: So basically, when I set the texture, I should call something like HouseDAO.updateFurniture(furniture). I had this idea before, but for some reason I rejected it...

Comment: Exactly. In this way, you can have the separation of concerns. And please, make sure to use interfaces.

Comment: Interfaces? What would that give me in this situation?

Comment: It's a matter of programming good practice. You use interfaces so that the class which calls the updateForniture method can ignore the real implementation. An example: you create the interface HouseDAO which declares the method updateForniture. Client classes will call that interface method. Then, you implement it persisting the modifications using JDBC for example. But what if your client prefers a JPA implementation? You have to implement a new class, but client classes still call the interface's method. Hope it's clear enough.

Comment: So it's a matter of abstraction then? I think I got it.